# CSS not working with PHP script

Tags: php, css

Hello i am following this tutorial to make a php calendar

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l76uglZBjpk

I have three files

show_calendar.php

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="calCss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
</head>
<body>
<?php include ("calendar_start.php"); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

calendar start.php

```
<?php
//$showmonth = $_POST['showmonth'];
//$showyear = $_POST['showyear'];
$showmonth = 11;
$showyear = 2012;

$day_count = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $showmonth, $showyear);
$pre_days = date('w', mktime(0,0,0, $showmonth, 1, $showyear));
$post_days = (6 - (date('w', mktime(0,0,0, $showmonth, $day_count,$showyear))));

echo '<div id="calendar_wrap">';
echo '<div class="title_bar">';
echo '<div class="previous_month"></div>';
echo 'div class="show_month">' . $showmonth . '/' . $showyear . '</div>';
echo '<div class="next_month"></div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="week_days">';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Sun</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Mon</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Tue</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Wed</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Thur</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Fri</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Sat</div>';
echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
echo '</div>';

/* Previous Month Filler Days */
if ($pre_days != 0) {
for($i = 1 ; $i<=$pre_days;$i++) {
    echo '<div class="non_cal_day"></div>';
}
}

/* Current Month */
for($i=1; $i<= $day_count; $i++) {
echo '<div class="cal_day">';
echo '<div class="day_heading">' . $i . '</div>';
echo '</div>';

}
/* Next Month Filler Days */
if ($post_days != 0) {
for ($i=1; $i<=$post_days; $i++) {
     echo '<div class="non_cal_day"></div>';
}
}
echo '</div>';
?>
```

and the css file   calCss.css

```
#calendar_wrap {
width: 924px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
overflow: hidden;
}
.title_bar {
width: 100%; 
height: 30px;
}
.previous_month {
float: left;
width: 308px;
height: 30px;
text-align: left;
}
.show_month {
float: left;
width: 308px;
height: 30px;
text-align: center;
}
.next_month {
float: left;
width: 308px;
height: 30px;
text-align: right;
}
.week_days {
width: 100%;
}       
.days_of_week  {
float: left;
width: 14%;
text-align: center;
}      
.cal_day {
position: relative;
float: left;
margin-right: 4px;
margin-bottom: 4px;
width: 128px;
height: 95px;
background-color: #9C9;
}
.day_heading {
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 40px;
height: 16px;
padding: 6px;
color: #000;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 14px;
}    
.openings {
width: 100%;
clear:left;
text-align: center;
}
.non_cal_day {
position: relative;
float: left;
margin-right: 4px;
margin-bottom: 4px;
width: 128px;
height: 95px;
background-color: #CCC;
}

.clear {
clear: both;
}
```

my problem is show_calendar.php is not showing any css only text of the days of teh week and numbers in the month. Im not sure what i could be doing wrong, does anyone have any ideas? Im using xampp local server to view the php file. Thanks

Comment: have you tried openening calCss.css in your browser? Is it showing the right contents?

Comment: Where is your .css ? In which folder ?

Comment: According to your PHP your CSS should be in the root folder (same as the PHP file) so make sure it is actually there - or call to the correct location of the CSS file.

Comment: When it comes to styling, only the resulting HTML (and CSS) matters, not the PHP that created it.

Comment: as mentioned above, check path of css file

Comment: maybe a typo, but you have `.days_of_week` in your CSS and div classes `days_of_the_week` in HTML

Comment: hey, it just shows the code if i open it in my browser

Comment: the css and php are in the same folder, how would i call the location of the css file?

Comment: the days of the week thing didnt make any difference and it wasnt a mistake as its the same in teh video

Comment: sorry where would i put start.php?

Comment: In the file "calendar start.php" line 13 is echo 'div class="show_month"> and it should be echo '<div class="show_month"> :)

Comment: thanks that made the month come up alright, but the css is still not showing :(

Comment: I tried it and it works fine for me using Google Chrome after renaming .days_of_week as @Wilq pointed out and correcting line 13 as I said. You could try to refresh the page in your browser using Shift + F5. I am unfortunatelly out of ideas. Good Luck!

Comment: ok thanks for trying, does the calender show up for you normally like in the video? i am using dreamweaver and xampp for the server, maybe im doing something wrong there

Comment: It shows like this: [image](http://postimage.org/image/f4mxcdyj9/)

Comment: thanks for doing that, i kind of have it worked out the local host on dreamweaver was set up wrong, the days of the week are still not showing up correctly but i should be able to figure that out, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I see just one small mistake:

you forgot one < here:
    `echo 'div class="show_month">' . $showmonth . '/' . $showyear . '</div>';`

I tested it like that and works fine for me..

Comment: css still doesnt work but it did fix the month showing up (it didnt before)

Comment: and your sure the css file has the exact same name as the one your calling? strange idd..

Comment: what browser (and version) are you on actually?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an IDE like ( dreamweaver ) for example , make sure that you set the Web URL for your localhost to  (localhost/myProject) not (localhost/myProject/index.php) .. because it sometimes makes error , reaching the css directory .. I had that error , and that fixed it , hope it works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

I've checked everything and found no reason why this shouldn't work. Probably your css file could not be loaded. You should check what you browser console says.

This is how you can debug this problem:

- start the script in your browser
- press **shift + strg + j** to start the developer tools (this shortcut works vor Forefox and Chrome f12 if you got IE)
- select 'console'
- check if there is an a loading error for your css

  If you're on windows then the second problem source could be hidden file extensions. Maybe your filename isn't *calCss.css* but *calCss.css.txt* or simmilar. This is only a guess but I had this type of problem before. If it applies to your problem **[this is how you can display hidden file extensions](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/28650-windows-8-display-file-extensions)**