# Php calendar css not linking

Tags: php, html, css, calendar

Now works. Solution was mainly syntax errors like - instead of _ or missing ;.

---

I am creating a calendar in php which later I will add events too. However currently my page is not linking with my style sheet. I know this appears to be a simple problem but I really can't see anything wrong with what I've got. Help is hugely appreciated as I can't move on until this is fixed. I haven't included all of my CSS as they are all pretty similar.

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="calstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
</head>
<body>
<?php include ("calendar_start.php"); ?>
</body>
</html>



<?php
//$showmonth = $_POST['showmonth'];
//$showyear = $_POST['showyear'];
$showmonth=9;
$showyear=2012;

$day_count = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $showmonth, $showyear);
$pre_days = date('w', mktime(0,0,0,$showmonth, 1, $showyear));
$post_days = (6-(date('w', mktime(0,0,0, $showmonth, $day_count, $showyear))));

echo '<div id="calendar_wrap">';
echo '<div class="title_bar">';
echo '<div class="previous_month"></div>';
echo '<div class="show_month">'  . date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $showmonth)) . ' ' . $showyear . '</div>';
echo '<div class="next_month"></div>';
echo '</div>';

echo '<div class="week_days">';


echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Sun</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Mon</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Tues</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Wed</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Thur</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Fri</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Sat</div>';
echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
echo '</div>';

if ($pre_days != 0) { 
    for($i=1; $i<=$pre_days; $i++) {
        echo '<div class="non_cal_day"></div>';
    }
}

for ($i=1; $i<= $day_count; $i++) {
    echo '<div class="cal_day">';
    echo '<div class="day_heading">' . $i . '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}

if ($post_days !=0) {
    for($i=1; $i<=$post_days; $i++) {
        echo '<div class="non_cal_day"></div>';
    }
}
echo '</div>';
?>
```

Start of CSS:

```
#calendar_wrap {
    width: 924px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.title_bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
}
.previous_month {
    float:left;
    width: 308px;
    height: 30px
    text-align: left;
}
.show_month {
    float: left;
    width: 308px;
    height: 30px
    text-align: center;
}
.next_month {
    float: left;
    width: 308px;
    height: 30px
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: where is your css file located?

Comment: try changing media"all" to media="all". If that doesn't work, check the pathing on your href

Comment: css is located in the same file as the other 2 files on my local host

Comment: Same problem here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223858/css-not-working-with-php-script?rq=1

Comment: Look in your browser's developer tools to see whether the style sheet is getting loaded.